# Using OS Sierra 10.12.6 Mac desktop and iPhone SE

Tags: macos, iphone

I have just updated my iPhone SE to 14.7.1 and now my Mac desktop running Sierra 10.12.6doesn't show any photos to import from the phone. Does this update mean I can no longer transfer photos from the phone?